# Why Plug-in Dependencies are Needed?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Hi I am trying to develop plugin project, I don't understand why i have to add plugin Dependencies, why can't i just add needed plugins' jars to the build path of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, because the OSGi framework manages the lifecycle of the plugins and takes care of loading, starting, stopping, and unloading the plugins when needed, so there's a lot more to the process than resolving the necessary dependencies. There are also extensions and extension points involved that allow you to expose various 'hooks' that could be used to extend your code. I recommend reading up on OSGi and the plugin framework.

Comment: More to the point, all of the dependencies are listed using your MANIFEST.MF file.  You shouldn't have to work with the Java Build Path manually.

Comment: Except for the specific case where you have implementation specific fragments to a plug-in, you should _never_ work with the build path. It is handled automatically based on your bundle dependencies (OSGi Require-Bundle and Import-Packages) and the bundle class path (OSGi Classpath header). The later s primary used for embedded jars.